# Can't combine more than one project on android studio like before

Tags: android-studio, ide, android-studio-girafee

When i uncheck the new ui on android studio giraffe, i can open more than one project in android studio but, if i check new UI, the project can't open together, honestly i love new UI but, how do i can combine more than two project in AS giraffe new UI ?

if uncheck the new UI, i can see more than project together.
if check the new UI, i can't see them.
but i like the new UI in android studio